# Error installig pjproject on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, linux

I'm installing pjproject on Ubuntu Linux. I'm trying to install the pjproject using this article:
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Build_Install
 Everything looks fine up through make dep .so files when I run make dep and make , i receive this error:

```
../src/pjmedia-audiodev/alsa_dev.c:37:28: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
/home/wissam/Downloads/pjproject-master/build/rules.mak:163: recipe for target 'output/pjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/alsa_dev.o' failed
make[2]: *** [output/pjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/alsa_dev.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/wissam/Downloads/pjproject-master/pjmedia/build'
Makefile:230: recipe for target 'libpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a' failed
make[1]: *** [libpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wissam/Downloads/pjproject-master/pjmedia/build'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me diagnose this error and resolve it?

Comment: You're missing developer files for alsa sound library. Should be in package `libasound2-dev` or similar for a recent Ubuntu. Probably other dev packages will be missing too, if you don't do this kind of thing often.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also don't forget te edit your question

Answer (score 0):

To build on @mkiever's comment, you're missing a library needed to compile the C language component. In C, in order to reference libraries, a line like `#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>` is included.

If you know you've installed this in the past, check your installation and path variables.  If not, the written instruction don't seem to do it for you.

In Ubuntu, the package you want can be installed with `sudo apt install libasound2-dev`.  After this installation, you should be able to install as expected.

Comment: thanks ...... but when enter command line   sudo apt install libasound2-dev the following wrong is appear                                                              E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: That's another issue outside of this particular installation.  I'd recommend rebooting and trying again, or checking the device here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process